# Multiclass classification not producing same output as yTrain data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to build a hand digit recognition model using sklearn digit data set.

My yTrain data set contains values from 0 to 9. But while I am testing module, with xTest data output is not in whole number i.e. 0 to 9. It is in fraction.

Any help would be appreciated. Accuracy score is also very low at about 0.5.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest =train_test_split(digits.data,digits.target,test_size=0.2)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(xTrain,yTrain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong model. `LinearRegression` is meant for regression, not classification. If you use for example `LogisticRegression` it works ok. See [sklearn help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) for multi-class classification models.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression(multi_class= "multinomial",max_iter=5000)
model.fit(xTrain,yTrain)

model.score(xTest,yTest)
0.9527777777777777
```